# Why is titanium not found in its pure state in nature?

Tags: reactivity

I am doing a research project on titanium and I know it is found in ores and compounds rather than in a pure state, but I am unsure why? How does this relate to its reactivity?

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{Ti}$, similarly as $\ce{Al}$, is more or less stable as metal not because it is not reactive, but because it is protected by passivation oxide layer.

Both metals are very reactive at high temperature. $\ce{Ti}$ burns in air before reaching melting point and is attacked by acids.

> Titanium is one of the few elements that burns in pure nitrogen gas, reacting at 800 °C (1,470 °F) to form titanium nitride.  ... Because of its high reactivity with oxygen, nitrogen, and some other gases, titanium filaments are applied in titanium sublimation pumps as scavengers for these gases. ( [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanium#Chemical_properties) )

This predicts the fact they are not found as free metals in the Earth crust, where high temperature high pressure chemistry is ongoing.

You may find useful reviewing [Wikipedia - Titanium - Chemical_properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanium#Chemical_properties) and/or searching for the same.